# JMETER non gui: Not able to generate folder using jmeter command line

Tags: java, macos, java-8, jmeter, macos-monterey

I am unable to generate a folder/HTML report of jmeter in the command line.

I have previously upgraded to the latest java and somehow it did not work.
I have downloaded `jdk8` but encountered this message below:

> jmeter: line 128: [: : integer expression expected jmeter: line 199:
> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home -v
> 1.8.331.09/bin/java: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong Java, you need to have [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (or at least [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Execution_environment)) and you seem to be using [Java browser plugin](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.html)

Follow the instructions from [Installation of the JDK on macOS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-2FE451B0-9572-4E38-A1A5-568B77B146DE) article to get the required version of Java (not earlier than JDK 8) and make sure that it's in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) before the one which is provided by the browser plugin.

Also you can consider using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for installing JMeter.

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Thank you!   this has resolved. i was copying the plugin jdk instead of the jdk se..